# Responsive design and internet explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, responsive-design, adsense

I'm using html5 template with responsive layout and it works just fine (in all major browsers).

I'm using wide, 728px ad (google adsense) in the header, and I would like to hide it, when viewport width is less than 728px. So I modified the css file - added

```
@media screen and (max-width: 728px) {
    .responsiveBanner {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

to the end of file. Everything works perfect in firefox and chrome. But IE10 doesn't hide the banner, when changing the window width.

modified code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 728px) {
    .responsiveBanner {
        display:none;
    }
    body {
            background:yellow;
    }
}
```

also doesn't hide the banner in IE, however, the background change is applied...

Do you have ayn idea, why IE doesn't hide the banner?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of IE? Only IE9+ supports media queries.

Comment: IE10, so there is the support

Comment: @tomas I can't [reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/zpqhd/) your issue with IE10. Please check your HTML is valid.

Answer (score 0):

IE has a few well known bugs, one of which is the one you've encountered.

try `visibility:hidden;`

Comment: also didn't help - I guess it has something to do with javascript generated content of that adsense banner...

Comment: Hmm. In that case, you might try moving it off the screen with absolute positioning and replacing it with a placeholder